# Disable requests to api.wordpress.org

Tags: updates, api, automatic-updates

I need to suppress outbound requests to api.wordpress.org somehow. They are taking like 1 seconds each and take so many time to load a page when I'm logged as admin.

I've searched for some solutions over the web but they don't seem to work.

Comment: I think WordPress as its own doesn't make any request to wordpress.org. Such requests are probably made by some plugin, like JetPack, that may need to make the requests to work. You should disable all plugins and use a default theme to see if such requests persists and to determine which plugin is making them.

Comment: @cybmeta WordPress make request to `api.wordpress.org` for checking core, plugin and theme updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can Disable HTTP Calls by adding this in your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', TRUE );
```

This will disable/block all external HTTP requests and will make website alot faster.

And then you can whitelist domains that you don't want to block.

```
define( 'WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', 'example.com, domain.com' );
```

Comment: thank you for save my day